# Geoserver : multiple layers of gwc in single url

Tags: google-maps, gis, postgis, layer, geoserver

i am hitting a geoserver URL from my application. it is returning unknown layers from geoserver but both the layer exist in geoserver.

Unknown layers URL : http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/**gwc**/service/wms?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetMap&VERSION=1.1.1&LAYERS=**layerA,layerB**&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/png&TRANSPARENT=true&HEIGHT=256&WIDTH=256&SRS=EPSG%3a3857&BBOX=-7909092.190723759,5213616.825275302,-7907869.198271196,5214839.817727864

Both the layers ( layerA and layerB exist in geoseerver ) . if i call individually it is returning the image. but in case of combined it is not returning any image and giving error of unknown layers..

Could we call multiple layers with GWC url ... ? if yes how we can do it Or answer is no than what is alternative way to call multiple gwc layers in single URL...

Comment: GWC returns cached tiles of a layer (or layer group) it doesn't work the way you think it does.

Comment: @IanTurton okay.. but both the layers in GWC..  if i create a layer group of both the layer than it is returning image...

Comment: yes, but they are in separate cache folders. Make two requests

Comment: @IanTurton Not possible to generate two request ... Actually its a API call and in API identifying two layers, so we need to hit both layers in a single request and return response back to API..

Comment: try enabling WMS integration and making a WMS request - might work?

Answer (score 0):

have 2 way:

1. Create a LayerGroup containing those 2 layers
2. Make 2 requests to call 2 layers

Comment: First option is an alternative way to achieve it.. i already implemented it and its working.. Second option not possible for me.. because i am calling through API and merging of two layers result on API.. Wont be possible.. or it will be slower.